# Two simple PHP files for localization that do basically the same, but one doesn't work?

Tags: php, localization

The multilingual content echoed with PHP (e.g. line 17) are not displayed at all.

**localizatoin.php:**

**This one works:**

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

if(isSet($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];

    // register the session and set the cookie
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
    setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else {
    $lang = 'en';
}

// use appropiate lang.xx.php file according to the value of the $lang
switch ($lang) {
case 'en':
    $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
    break;

case 'es':
    $lang_file = 'lang.es.php';
    break;

case 'zh-tw':
    $lang_file = 'lang.zh-tw.php';
    break;

case 'zh-cn':
    $lang_file = 'lang.zh-cn.php';
    break;

default:
    $lang_file = 'lang.en.php';
}

//translation helper function
function l($localization) {
    global $lang;
    return $lang[$localization];
}

    include_once 'languages/'.$lang_file;
?>
```

**This one:**

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

function get_lang(){
    if(!empty($_GET['lang'])) return $_GET['lang'];
    if(!empty($_SESSION['lang'])) return $_SESSION['lang'];
    if(!empty($_COOKIE['lang'])) return $_COOKIE['lang'];
    return 'en';
}

function set_lang($lang){
    setcookie("lang", $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
}

function get_lang_file($lang){
    $lang_file = "languages/lang.$lang.php";
    if(file_exists($lang_file)) return $lang_file;
    if($lang_file = get_lang_file('en')) return $lang_file;
    return false;
}

//translation helper function
function l($string){
    static $localization;

    if(!isset($localization)){
        $lang = get_lang();
        $lang_file = get_lang_file($lang);
        if($lang_file) set_lang($lang);
        $localization = include $lang_file;
    }

    return $localization[$string];
}

?>
```

**displays the following error:**

```
Notice: Undefined variable: lang_file in D:\wamp\www\test2\localization0.1\index.php on line 17
(and so on)
```

**languages/lang.en.php (sample):**

```
<?php
$lang = array(
    'tagline_p' => "Hello!...",
(continues)
```

**index.php (sample):**

```
    <?php
include_once 'localization.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Web design and Translation / 網頁設計和翻譯" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="web development, web developer, web design, web designer, translation, translator, taiwan, taipei, taichung, english, chinese, spanish, 網站開發者, 網頁設計, 網頁設計師, 翻譯, 翻譯著, 台灣, 台北, 台中, 英文, 中文, 西班牙文, html, css, javascript, php" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7"/>
    <title>Alex Chen - Web design and Translation / 網頁設計和翻譯</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/reset.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.css" />
    <?php if(get_lang() == 'zh-tw' || 'zh-cn') {echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/chinese.css" />';} ?>
(continues)
```

**line 17:**

```
<?php if($lang_file=='lang.zh-tw.php' || $lang_file=='lang.zh-cn.php') {echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/chinese.css" />';} ?>
```

**line 23 to 26**:

```
<ul id="lang">
        <li <?php if($lang_file=='lang.en.php') {echo 'class="current"';} ?>><a href="index.php?lang=en">ENGLISH</a></li>
        <li <?php if($lang_file=='lang.es.php') {echo 'class="current"';} ?>><a href="index.php?lang=es">ESPAÑOL</a></li>
        <li <?php if($lang_file=='lang.zh-tw.php') {echo 'class="current"';} ?>><a href="index.php?lang=zh-tw">中文(繁體)</a></li>
        <li <?php if($lang_file=='lang.zh-cn.php') {echo 'class="current"';} ?>><a href="index.php?lang=zh-cn">中文(简体)</a></li>
```

Comment: "Notice: Undefined variable: "  That's not necessarily an error.  It may indicate a condition that's causing an error.  It's certainly something that should be dealt with, as it's bad coding practice and can lead to errors.  What are the actual errors?

Comment: Would make sense to look in line 17 of index.php, which you didn't post here. Apart from that, in the second example there is a file_exists() check, so if the include file isn't in ./languages/lang.en.php but somewhere else within the include_path, that might explain it.

Comment: OK I added line 17, the error is that those php echo's in index.php are not being displayed.

Comment: Where is $lang_file defined in index.php?  And, seriously, what about the rest of the errors? Are we to guess what "and so on" means?

Comment: @George Marian Sorry, I just added where $lang_file is defined in index.php. Line 17, 23 to 26.

Comment: $lang_files is probably not being set.  That notice you posted is complaining about the fact that $lang_file is not defined at that point in index.php

Comment: Show us the first 17 lines of index.php, please.

Comment: OK I edited the post. I changed if(lang_file to if(get_lang, and now I'm just having problem with line 17.

Comment: Never mind, using get_lang instead of lang_file fixed the issues, thanks.

Comment: You still have a problem in that code.  Does index.php?lang=zh-cn work?

Comment: @George Marian, yes I fixed the issue:  <?php if(get_lang() == 'zh-tw' || get_lang() == 'zh-cn') {echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/chinese.css" />';} ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't be an inappropriately lazy programmer!

```
$lang = get_lang();
if($lang == 'zh-tw' || $lang == 'zh-cn')
{
 ...
}
```

Edit: Explanation of the code.

This is simply line 17, expanded into multiple lines.  Unless the if statement is truly simple, it is best to avoid single line if statements.  This is easier to read.

This assigns the return value of get_lang() to a variable:

```
$lang = get_lang();
```

This tests if that lang variable contains either 'zh-tw' or 'zh-ch':

```
if($lang == 'zh-tw' || $lang == 'zh-cn')
```

It's late and I'm tired, but I don't think this actually does much of anything:

```
if(get_lang() == 'zh-tw' || 'zh-cn')
```

It evaluates to true, but that's because of the way PHP evaluates types in a boolean context.  Those are strings and they're not empty.  They evaluate to true.  The return value of get_lang() is tossed away by PHP and not used, as it's not being assigned to a variable.

Comment: Haha calm down man, I'm not a PHP programmer, I'm just a designer. Can you explain the code you just wrote?

Comment: @janoChen Oh, I'm calm.  That exclamation point was meant to drive the point home, not convey my state of mind. :)  Explanation incoming, in the answer.